# Javascript: pass method of object as pointer

Tags: javascript, pointers, p5.js

Here is my code:

```
function active_area(width, t_width, height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.t_width = t_width; //width of toolbar

    this.dotes  = 20;
    this.gridStep = this.width/this.dotes;

    this.active_layer = -1;
    this.layers_array = [];

}
    active_area.prototype.init = function () {
        this.canvas = createCanvas(this.width+this.t_width, this.height);
        this.canvas.parent('mapper');

        this.addButton(10, 10, 'Zoom out', this.zoomOut);
        this.addButton(10, 50, 'Zoom in', this.zoomIn);
        this.addButton(30, 30, 'Add layer', this.addLayer);

        this.drawGrid();
    };

    active_area.prototype.addButton = function(x, y, name, func){
        var pos_x = this.width+x;
        var add_layer = createDiv();
        add_layer.position(pos_x, height + y);
        add_layer.html('<paper-button>'+name+'</paper-button>');
        add_layer.mouseClicked(func);
    };

    active_area.prototype.zoomOut = function () {
        console.log('zoom out');
        console.log('dotes:'+this.dotes);
        this.dotes = this.dotes*2;
        console.log('dotes:'+this.dotes);
        redraw();
        //this.drawGrid();
    };
```

Problem in a method zoomOut: i cann't access this.dotes from class active_area, drawGrid cann't access to. This method calls fine, listener works, but how to access class scope?

Comment: Where exactly are you defining `this.dotes`? Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Stop minus me, i showed normal part of the code and i said, that i cann't access class scope. Or this information less for you? I cann't post more code because get message "to match code"

Comment: We need to be able to run your code to help you debug it. We're not asking for more code. In fact, it should probably be less code. But it should be **just enough** code so we can copy and paste it to run it ourselves. That means removing the stuff that has nothing to do with your problem, and adding everything we need to see the problem ourselves. You also might use JSFiddle or CodePen to create an example that we can run.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: ok, i've understood. I don't know about this service, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind it

```
this.addButton(10, 10, 'Zoom out', this.zoomOut.bind(this));
this.addButton(10, 50, 'Zoom in', this.zoomIn.bind(this));
this.addButton(30, 30, 'Add layer', this.addLayer.bind(this));
```

Comment: We can't know for sure because the OP hasn't given us their full code, but I believe the issue is that they are not binding the this context when calling the init function from their class definition. As a result, the this context is binding to the prototype object rather than the class itself.

Comment: Assuming that the this is pointing to the prototype, another way to get the class's context from the prototype is to call `prototype.constructor`. In this case, it would be `this.zoomOut.bind(this.constructor)`

Comment: 99% of the time, this is the issue where the event context is to something else. One can make assumptions with limited code, that is how we get through our daily jobs debugging errors in code.

Comment: ^^^ @МаксимСтукало Please post more of your relevant code!

Comment: redraw - imported function  from processing.js. Stack limits me. I've added main function. Sorry, forget

Comment: The thing is I answered your first question so that original bug is fixed and that opened up a new bug and I have no idea what that new bug is since there is no details on what breaks. So it basically is a new question.